# MDCTextField rightView property broken on iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, material-components

I can't use the `rightView` property with `MDCTextField` anymore on iOS 13. Am I the only one having an issue with this?

The right view width cover the whole text field: preventing the user interaction and hiding the textView content.

No problem when I switch from `MDCTextField` to `UITextField`.

Comment: Issue created on the GitHub repo here: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/issues/8492

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add **width** `constraint` to the `rightView`/`leftView`.

Don't forget to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

```swift
rightView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
rightView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: <#NeededWidth#>).isActive = true
// This is enough to make it act like before but you can set other missing constraints like height to suppress layout warnings and prevent further issues.
// rightView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: <#HeightOfTheTextField#>).isActive = true
```

You may notice some autolayout warnings in the consule because you didn't set the missing constraint for the `rightView`/`leftView`. So add missing constraints or simply ignore those.

And note that if the `rightView`/`leftView` is some kind of `StackView`, try to putting it inside a `view` and then add this view instead.

Comment: I had this issue with the original `UITextField` (since beta 3 I think) and after doing the mentioned method, It fixed.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, adding a constraint to the `textField.rightView` looks like the cleanest workaround. I will replace the manual resizing frame by a dynamic width constraint.

Comment: Actually it’s an explicit way to achieve that. Autolayout *usually* works for *almost* anything. Please don’t forget to assign the bounty as well and feel free to ask any further question.

Comment: Just did. I didn't notice before autolayout could also work with `textField.rightView`.

Comment: I don't know why yet, but it looks like interaction with the right view button subviews doesn't work anymore through width autolayout...

Comment: Could you provide minimal working code? So I can try to find the bug.

Comment: Nevermind it's working fine on a new project. The issue is coming from my own code. I'll sort it out by myself, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Apparently this was a change in the way `rightViewRect(forBounds:)` behaves in iOS 13 Beta 5.

From the [iOS & iPadOS 13 Developer Beta 5 Release Notes](http://web.archive.org/web/20190801231842/https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_ipados_13_beta_5_release_notes):

> UIKit - Resolved Issues
>
> Prior to iOS 13, UITextField assumed that the frames of its leftView and rightView were correctly set when assigned and would never change. Starting in iOS 13, the implementation of leftViewRect(forBounds:) and rightViewRect(forBounds:) now ask the view for its systemLayoutSizeFitting(*:). To achieve the previous behavior when linking against and running on iOS 13, add explicit sizing constraints on the view, wrap it in a plain UIView, or subclass the view and implement systemLayoutSizeFitting(*:). (51787798)

The [MDCTextField](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/blob/develop/components/TextFields/src/MDCTextField.m) `-(CGRect)rightViewRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds` function needs to be updated.